# fabric.js library with angular 4

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I need some draggable dynamic element on canvas so for that I have to use fabric.js. for testing I have installed fabric in my machine by following these steps.

1. npm install fabric
2. npm install fabric --save
3. npm install @types/fabric --save-dev
4. wrote this code in my component

```js
       import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from "@angular/core";
    import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material";
    import { MountingTypeComponent } from './mounting-type/mounting-type.component';
    import 'fabric';
    declare let fabric;
    @Component({
      selector: "app-custom-report",
      templateUrl: "./custom-report.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./custom-report.component.scss"]
    })
    export class CustomReportComponent implements OnInit {
      private canvas;
    private boundbox;
    private shape;
      animal: string;
      constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
      openDialog(): void {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MountingTypeComponent, {
          height: '275px',
          data: { animal: this.animal }
        });
    
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log("The dialog was closed");
          this.animal = result;
        });
      }
      ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    
    });
    
    this.boundbox = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 500,
    height: 600,
    fill: 'trans',
    stroke: 'grey',
    strokeDashArray: [5, 5]
    });
    
    this.shape = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    fill: 'red'
    });
    this.canvas.add(this.boundbox);
    this.canvas.add(this.shape);
    this.canvas.centerObject(this.boundbox);
    
      }
    
    
    
    }
    
    
    // @Component({
    //   selector: "dialog-overview-example-dialog",
    //   templateUrl: "dialog-overview-example-dialog.html"
    // })
    // export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {
    //   constructor(
    //     public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    //     @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
    //   ) {}
    
    //   onNoClick(): void {
    //     this.dialogRef.close();
    //   }
    // }
```

Though it is running and has drawn some figure and also in the console, I did not got any error but when I was installing I got many errors. will they create problems when I will start creating for real?

```
>npm install fabric

> contextify@0.1.15 install E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\nod
e-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\shekhar\my-sun-app
 - Copy\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
 "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> canvas@1.6.7 install E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gy
p-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\GTK\bin\zlib1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libexpat-1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libpng14-14.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libcairo-2.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libfontconfig-1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libfreetype-6.dll
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\shekhar\my-sun-app
 - Copy\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
 "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
my-sun-app@0.0.0 E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.4.6
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.4.6
`-- fabric@1.7.19

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win
32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@0.0.0-NG but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@0.0.0-NG but none was installed.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.0.49 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34 but none was installed.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 (node_modules\contextify):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: canvas@1.6.7 (node_modules\canvas):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: canvas@1.6.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy>npm install fabric --save

> contextify@0.1.15 install E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\nod
e-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\shekhar\my-sun-app
 - Copy\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
 "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> canvas@1.6.7 install E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gy
p-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\GTK\bin\zlib1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libexpat-1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libpng14-14.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libcairo-2.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libfontconfig-1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libfreetype-6.dll
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\shekhar\my-sun-app
 - Copy\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
 "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
my-sun-app@0.0.0 E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.4.6
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.4.6
`-- fabric@1.7.19

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win
32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@0.0.0-NG but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@0.0.0-NG but none was installed.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.0.49 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34 but none was installed.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 (node_modules\contextify):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: canvas@1.6.7 (node_modules\canvas):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: canvas@1.6.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy>npm install @types/fabric --save --dev
npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--only=dev` instead.
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5620-949
0b247\registry.npmjs.org\_40types\fabric\-\fabric-1.5.27.tgz.3222728418' -> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-5620-9490b247\registry.npmjs
.org\_40types\fabric\-\fabric-1.5.27.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "@types/fabric" "
--save" "--dev"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy>npm install @types/fabric --save-dev

> contextify@0.1.15 install E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\nod
e-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\shekhar\my-sun-app
 - Copy\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
 "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> canvas@1.6.7 install E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gy
p-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\GTK\bin\zlib1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libexpat-1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libpng14-14.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libcairo-2.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libfontconfig-1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libfreetype-6.dll
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\shekhar\my-sun-app
 - Copy\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
 "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
my-sun-app@0.0.0 E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.4.6
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.4.6
`-- @types/fabric@1.5.27

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win
32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@0.0.0-NG but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@0.0.0-NG but none was installed.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.0.49 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34 but none was installed.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 (node_modules\contextify):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: canvas@1.6.7 (node_modules\canvas):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: canvas@1.6.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy>npm update
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6436-f0c
8371e\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular\flex-layout\-\flex-layout-2.0.0-rc.1.tgz.139488422' -> 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6436-f0c8371e
\registry.npmjs.org\_40angular\flex-layout\-\flex-layout-2.0.0-rc.1.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

> contextify@0.1.15 install E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\nod
e-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\shekhar\my-sun-app
 - Copy\node_modules\contextify\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
 "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> canvas@1.6.7 install E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gy
p-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\GTK\bin\zlib1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libexpat-1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libpng14-14.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libcairo-2.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libfontconfig-1.dll
C:\GTK\bin\libfreetype-6.dll
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install
 Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [E:\shekhar\my-sun-app
 - Copy\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:219:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
 "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
my-sun-app@0.0.0 E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.4.6
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.4.6
+-- @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-rc.1
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.8.18

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win
32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-rc.1 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.0.49 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34 but none was installed.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 (node_modules\contextify):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: contextify@0.1.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: canvas@1.6.7 (node_modules\canvas):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: canvas@1.6.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\shekhar\my-sun-app - Copy\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you developing in Visual Studio? Are you using gulp, or angular-cli?
It's a little hard to determine where the problem lays.

Did you add the third-party package to you gulp/angular-cli if you are using either one of them?

Comment: @DavidMørch, I am using VS code editor angular-cli. yes I have updated NPM. and No, I am not using gulp.

Comment: Okay, great. Did you add the dependency to your **angular-cli.json**? 
Like this:
---
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
      ]?

Of course it should be the right path, for your package.

Comment: Nope. I have not added any dependency though. just followed this tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b48wnQtfwzs